# Client and server side both have the updated data but rendering doesn't show the updated data

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, fetch

The technologies I am using are: Nodejs, Express, MySQL, EJS.

What I am doing:

Have an app.get which gets the needed data(posts) from MySQL and then renders a file using that data

```
app.get("/" + element.name, function(req, res){
    connection.query(`SELECT * FROM sub ${element.name} posts`, function(error, result) {

        if(error) {
            console.log(`Nick error`)
        } else {
            console.log(`Works get !`)
            posts = result;
        }
    });

    res.render("sub" + element.name, {posts:posts}), console.log(posts + " Here")
```

When someone visits that url, that data(posts) is rendered and a FETCH POST request is made using that data(I am using the length of it),

```
// Before this, the data gets mapped into the variable called "final"
console.log("!!!###")
console.log(`Above the FETCH`)
console.log(`yes in normal position  1 `)
console.log(` BTW ${JSON.stringify(final)}`) // I CAN SEE THE NEW POST HERE #########################

fetch(`/ookook`, { method: 'POST', body: JSON.stringify(final), headers: new Headers({ "Content-Type": "application/json" }) })
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(jsonRes => {
      console.log(`yes in normal position 2 `)
      console.log(`DRAGON BTW ${JSON.stringify(final)}`) // I CAN SEE THE NEW POST HERE ###############################
  })
```

The POST request then sees the lenght of the data(posts) and for each data(It's an array of array of objects, so it does this for each array of array) creates a app.get route, the url is "/pagename/2" (the number gets incremented)

```
 app.post("/" + element.name, function(req, res) {

     for(let i = 0; i < req.body.length; i++) {

         for(let b = 0; b < req.body[i].length; b++) {
             console.log(req.body[i][b].id)
             let posts = req.body[i];
             console.log(posts) // I CAN SEE THE NEW POST HERE ###########################
             console.log("in app.post friendo")
             app.get(`/${element.name}/${i + 2}`, function(req, res) {
                 res.render("sub"+ element.name, { posts:posts})
             })
         }
     }
     res.status(200).json({voteNum: 5}) // Ignore the voteNum       
 });
```

The problem: When I create a new post, it gives it to my DB and I can see it in my client and server side using console.log BUT, it doesn't render it. For me to see the post I have to restart my server.

I wrote "`// I CAN SEE THE POST HERE #############`" in the code where I can see the new post in the console.log(server/client side) BUT it doesn't get rendered

Comment: how about moving "    res.render("sub" + element.name, {posts:posts}), console.log(posts + " Here") " into the callback of connection.query ?

Comment: @FadiAboMsalam I tried it but it sadly did not work.

Answer (score 0):

when starting script, starting your server, `app` which is `express` and all it's middlewares are set.

Your change won't work unless restart server, reset `app`.

I think your concept is not correct

**First**

maybe try something like this

```
let list = [];
//list is the data in posts, you can init it by query the DB.
app.get('/:elementname' ,()=>{
   //check whether req.params.elementname match list
   //if match, it is a validate url, or else 404 NOT FOUND=>call next() 
})
app.post('/newPostName', ()=>{
    //add new post to DB and update list.
})
```

**Second**

By the way,

You better check whether `connection.query` is a async function or not.

if it is, the code should be

```
connection.query('query...' ,()=>{
   //...
   res.render()
})
```

not

```
connection.query('query...' ,()=>{
   //...
})
res.render()
```